# Conditional response of a linear mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, variance, random-effects-model

Consider the linear mixed effects model:

\begin{equation}
X_i(t_{ij}) = \eta + Z_i(t_{ij})w_i + \epsilon_{ij},
\end{equation}

where $\eta$ is the mean, $Z_i(t_{ij}) = [1, \log(t_{ij})]$, $w_i = (w_{0i}, w_{1i})' \sim N(0,\Sigma_{w})$, $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, and

\begin{equation}
\Sigma_{w} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2_1&  \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\
\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma^2_2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

The conditional response is given by

\begin{equation}
X_i(t_{ij}) \mid w_i, \eta, \theta, \sigma \sim N(\eta + Z_i(t_{ij})w_i, \sigma^2),
\end{equation}

where $\theta = c(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \rho)$.

But, the variance of $X_i$ is

\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
Cov(X_i(t_i), X_i(t_i)) & = Cov(\eta + Z_i(t_i)w_i + \epsilon_i, \eta + Z_i(t_i)w_i + \epsilon_i) \\
& = Var(Z_i(t_i)w_i) + Var(\epsilon_i) = Z_i(t_i)\Sigma_{w}Z'_i(t_i) + \sigma^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

So, why is the conditional response not given by

\begin{equation}
X_i(t_{ij}) \mid w_i, \eta, \theta, \sigma \sim N(\eta, Z_i(t_i)\Sigma_{w}Z'_i(t_i) + \sigma^2).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I misunderstood.

The conditional response is given by

\begin{equation}
X_i(t_{ij}) \mid w_i \sim N(\eta + Z_i(t_{ij})w_i, \sigma^2).
\end{equation}

And, the marginal distribution is given by:

\begin{equation}
X_i(t_{ij}) \sim N(\eta, Z_i(t_i)\Sigma_{w}Z'_i(t_i) + \sigma^2).
\end{equation}

Ref: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002437951100320X